# GST Validation through state code in regex is not working in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have written Perl code for validating GSTIN Number through State code selected by customer according to the following rules:

- The first two digits represent the state code as per Indian Census 2011. Every state has a unique code.
- The next ten digits will be the PAN number of the taxpayer
- The thirteenth digit will be assigned based on the number of registration within a state
- The fourteenth digit will be Z by default
- The last digit will be for check code. It may be an alphabet or a number.

Following is the code:

```
my $gst_number_input = '35AABCS1429B1AX';

my $gst_number_character_count = length($gst_number_input);

my $state_code = '35';

my $gst_validation = qr/$state_code[A-Z]{5}\d{4}[A-Z][A-Z\d]Z[A-Z\d]/;

if ($gst_number_character_count == 15 && $gst_number_input =~ $gst_validation) {

    print "GST Number is valid";

} else {

    print "Invalid GST Number";
}
```

I have GSTIN input which matches with the state code in the script. So when I run the script, I get:

`Invalid GST Number`

Instead I should get:

`GST Number is valid`

Can anyone please help ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In this example string `35AABCS1429B1AX`, if you expect GST Number is valid then the A in `AX` should be a `Z` because you expect it in `Z[A-Z\d]` right?

Comment: You have mentioned ```The fourteenth digit will be Z by default``` in your rule and in the variable ```$gst_number_input = '35AABCS1429B1AX'``` you have ```A``` in fourteenth position.

Comment: Thank you and sorry about the blunder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state that the fourteenth character is a 'Z'.

So your code works. The fourteenth character in `$gst_number_input` is an 'A'.

Change the input code so that your input has a Z in the right spot and you will get `GST Number is valid`.

```
my $gst_number_input = '35AABCS1429B1ZX';
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry about the blunder

Answer (score 1):

Probably you would prefer to have the check in form of subroutine

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $debug = 0;

my @gst_numbers = <DATA>;

my $state_code = 35;

foreach my $gst_number (@gst_numbers) {
    chomp $gst_number;
    printf "%s %s\n",
            $gst_number, 
            validate_gst($gst_number,$state_code) 
            ? "valid" : "invalid";
}

sub validate_gst {
    my $gst_number = shift;
    my $state_code = shift;

    my %code;

    printf "%s : %s\n", 
            $gst_number, $state_code
            if $debug;

    my $gst_regex = qr/(\d{2})([A-Z\d]{10})(\d)(Z)([A-Z\d])/;

    return 0 if length $gst_number < 15;

    if( $gst_number =~ $gst_regex ) {
        @code{qw(st pan d z x)} = ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5);

        printf "ST: %s PAN: %s D: %s Z: %s X: %s\n", 
                $code{st},  # state code
                $code{pan}, # PAN number
                $code{d},   # state reg number
                $code{z},   # Z
                $code{x}    # check code
                if $debug;

        return 0 if $code{st}+0 != $state_code;             # state match?
        return 0 if $code{pan}  !~ /[A-Z]{5}\d{4}[A-Z\d]/;  # PAN correct?
        return 0 if $code{d}    !~ /\d/;                    # state reg number?
        return 0 if $code{z}    !~ /Z/;                     # Z?
                                                            # check code?
        return 1;   # check passed
    } else {
        return 0;   # check not passed
    }
}

__DATA__
1234567890123Z5
35AABCS1429B1AX
121234567890DZD
37AABCS6428B1AX
35AABCS2439B1ZX
42AABCS1429B1AX
35AABCS1729B1ZX
```

Polar Bear

Comment: Technically speaking last two checks are unnecessary as they was done in regex earlier -- but make code more readable and easier to understand. You can expand the code further if it will require to do so to make more checks.